# Prove vector spaces are isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{F}$ and that $T : V → V$ is an isomorphism.

Prove that if $S : V → V$ is also a linear transformation and $ST$ is an
isomorphism, then $S$ is an isomorphism.

I'm assuming $ST$ means $S\circ T$ i.e. a compostion.

I am lost on where I should start and what I should prove.

Comment: think about $T^{-1}$

Comment: It could be useful to show the composition of isomorphisms is an isomorphism. Then $T^{-1}$ is an isomorphism and $ST\circ T^{-1}=S$ is an isomorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

Regarding $S$ it only remains to show that it is bijective
Also use the fact that in a finite dimensional space injective $\iff $ onto

Easier to show onto here:

Let $v_1\in V$ since $ST$ is  an isomorphism $\exists v\in V$ such that $ST(v)=v_1\implies S(T(v))=v_1$ where $T(v)\in V$.Hence $S$ is onto